# Getting two outputs from Keras model

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I want to extend the output of the network to two outputs in this code

```
 def tag_dataset(self, dataset, model):
    """Tag data with numerical values"""
    correctLabels = []
    predLabels = []

    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
        tokens, casing, char, labels = data
        tokens = np.asarray([tokens])
        casing = np.asarray([casing])
        char = np.asarray([char])
        pred = model.predict([tokens, casing, char], verbose=False)[0]
        pred = pred.argmax(axis=-1)  
        correctLabels.append(labels)
        predLabels.append(pred) 
    return predLabels, correctLabels



def buildModel(self):
    """Model layers"""
    # character input
    character_input = Input(shape=(None, 52,), name="Character_input")
    embed_char_out = TimeDistributed(
        Embedding(len(self.char2Idx), 30, embeddings_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=-0.5, maxval=0.5)), name="Character_embedding")(
        character_input)

    dropout = Dropout(self.dropout)(embed_char_out)

    # CNN
    conv1d_out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(kernel_size=self.conv_size, filters=30, padding='same', activation='tanh', strides=1), name="Convolution")(dropout)
    maxpool_out = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(52), name="Maxpool")(conv1d_out)
    char = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name="Flatten")(maxpool_out)
    char = Dropout(self.dropout)(char)

    # word-level input
    words_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='words_input')
    words = Embedding(input_dim=self.wordEmbeddings.shape[0], output_dim=self.wordEmbeddings.shape[1], weights=[self.wordEmbeddings],
                      trainable=False)(words_input)

    # case-info input
    casing_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='casing_input')
    casing = Embedding(output_dim=self.caseEmbeddings.shape[1], input_dim=self.caseEmbeddings.shape[0], weights=[self.caseEmbeddings],
                       trainable=False)(casing_input)

    # concat & BLSTM
    output = concatenate([words, casing, char])
    output = Bidirectional(LSTM(self.lstm_state_size, 
                                return_sequences=True, 
                                dropout=self.dropout,                        # on input to each LSTM block
                                recurrent_dropout=self.dropout_recurrent     # on recurrent input signal
                               ), name="BLSTM")(output)
    output1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(self.label2Idx), activation='softmax'),name="Softmax_layer1")(output)
    output2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(self.label2Idx), activation='softmax'),name="Softmax_layer2")(output)    #This line is added

    # set up model
    self.model = Model(inputs=[words_input, casing_input, character_input], outputs= [output1, output2])
    self.model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', loss_weights=[0.5, 0.5], optimizer=self.optimizer)

    self.init_weights = self.model.get_weights()

    plot_model(self.model, to_file='model.png')
    print("Model built. Saved model.png\n")

def train(self):
    """Default training"""

    self.f1_test_history = []
    self.f1_dev_history = []

    for epoch in range(self.epochs):    
        print("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, self.epochs))
        for i,batch in enumerate(iterate_minibatches(self.train_batch,self.train_batch_len)):

            labels, tokens, casing, char = batch 

            self.model.train_on_batch([tokens, casing, char], [labels, labels] )

        # compute F1 scores
        predLabels, correctLabels = self.tag_dataset(self.test_batch, self.model)
        pre_test, rec_test, f1_test = compute_f1(predLabels, correctLabels, self.idx2Label)
```

The original code is at https://github.com/mxhofer/Named-Entity-Recognition-BidirectionalLSTM-CNN-CoNLL.git.

Just adding that Dense layer for getting two outputs, is enough? I added that Dense layer, but it gives the error for `compute_f1' which is defined as

```
def compute_f1(predictions, correct, idx2Label):
label_pred = []
for sentence in predictions:
    label_pred.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

label_correct = []
for sentence in correct:
    label_correct.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

# print("predictions ", len(label_pred))
# print("correct labels ", len(label_correct))

prec = compute_precision(label_pred, label_correct)
rec = compute_precision(label_correct, label_pred)

f1 = 0
if (rec + prec) > 0:
    f1 = 2.0 * prec * rec / (prec + rec);

return prec, rec, f1
```

the error is

```
 in train
  pre_test, rec_test, f1_test = compute_f1(predLabels, correctLabels, self.idx2Label)
  File "...", line 10, in compute_f1
label_pred.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])
   File "...", line 10, in <listcomp>
label_pred.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])
  TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: It'd be better if you included how you prepare your data and cal the fit function here, rather than linking to another gihub link. From the error, it seems that you are passing only one target/label to your model while it expects two. If your target is the same, you should duplicate it and pass it as a list.

Comment: @BashirKazimi thanks. I added more details. I duplicated the label as you said `self.model.train_on_batch([tokens, casing, char], [labels, labels] )' that error is solved but I think because the labels are a list of NumPy arrays, another error has appeared in compute_f1. How can I solve that?

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. Maybe upvote the comment then? :) also regarding your new error, again, you should treat it as list. Now, your compute_f1 function thinks each example is a vector, you should treat it as a list.

Comment: upvoted :) would you please explain more? Since now predLabels, correctLabels are not lists, since `pred = model.predict([tokens, casing, char], verbose=False)[0]' , idx2Label also is not a list, how compute_f1 function should be changed?

Comment: I added the compute_f1 function as an answer for readability, it is not tested, but you get the idea, please adjust as you see fit. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: reply based on the comments under original post**

Since you are calculating f1 for the same values but based on two predictions, you could calculate it for both predictions and take the average. without any validation for correctness, I am writing a code below:

```
def compute_f1(predictions, correct, idx2Label):
    prediction_1 = predictions[0]
    correct_1 = correct[0]
    label_pred = []
    for sentence in prediction_1:
        label_pred.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

    label_correct = []
    for sentence in correct_1:
        label_correct.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

    # print("predictions ", len(label_pred))
    # print("correct labels ", len(label_correct))

    prec_1 = compute_precision(label_pred, label_correct)
    rec_1 = compute_precision(label_correct, label_pred)

    f1_1 = 0
    if (rec_1 + prec_1) > 0:
        f1_1 = 2.0 * prec_1 * rec_1 / (prec_1 + rec_1);

    prediction_2 = predictions[1]
    correct_2 = correct[1]
    label_pred = []
    for sentence in prediction_2:
        label_pred.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

    label_correct = []
    for sentence in correct_2:
        label_correct.append([idx2Label[element] for element in sentence])

    # print("predictions ", len(label_pred))
    # print("correct labels ", len(label_correct))

    prec_2 = compute_precision(label_pred, label_correct)
    rec_2 = compute_precision(label_correct, label_pred)

    f1_2 = 0
    if (rec_2 + prec_2) > 0:
        f1_2 = 2.0 * prec_2 * rec_2 / (prec_2 + rec_2);

    # taking average
    prec = (prec_1 + prec_2)/2.
    rec = (rec_1 + rec_2)/2.
    f1 = (f1_1 + f1_2)/2.

    return prec, rec, f1
```

Comment: thnaks @Bashir Kazimi , I applied a change over  tag_dataset function, `labels = [labels]
            correctLabels.append(labels)' , now the code runs without error but the output f1_dev is 0 and doesn't change

Comment: It seems the code does not perform correctly. I wonder by considering two outputs from model, `pred = model.predict([tokens, casing, char], verbose=False)[0]' in function tag_dataset shouldn't be changed? it is generating two predictions at the same time for two outputs?